# Why lithium looses electron more easily than sodium according to electrode potential values?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

As lithium is smaller in size than that of sodium, then sodium should loose electron more easily than lithium

Comment: Sodium **does** lose electron more easily than lithium; check the ionization energies and you'll see just that. Electrode potentials are more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, the Lithium atom is smaller than Sodium. But the Sodium nucleus attracts its outer electron much stronger than Lithium, at it has 11 protons, and Lithium only 3. So both effects (size and charge) have to be taken into account. Apparently the size effect is not dominant.

Comment: Consider also the electron shielding effect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shielding_effect?wprov=sfla1   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules?wprov=sfla1